# Privacy of the a Facebook timeline photo posted to one friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I posted a Facebook photo to the news feed from the mobile app. (I presume this is the equivalent of adding it to my own timeline).

My privacy settings for individual posts at the time were to share with one person only, but in the photo I tagged another person.

What I do know:

- the person who was in my settings can see the photo
- the person tagged in the photo can see the photo
- other people can't see the item in my feed

What I need to know:

- can people who are friends of the tagged person now see the photo and the subsequent comments, or does the fact I initially restricted it to one person prevent this from happening? In other words does tagging a person blow the initial settings away?

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to know:
>
> - can people who are friends of the tagged person now see the photo and the subsequent comments, or does the fact I initially restricted it to one person prevent this from happening? In other words does tagging a person blow the initial settings away?

Yes, the moment you tag a person, that person + their friends will be able to see all activity